# PHP-Function call

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I designed plain html site,with one enquiry form.It has some fields like name ,address etc.
Onclick of **submit** button,i wanted this data to go into the  database.
I  created database and table using **phpmyadmin** on **XAMPP** server.

My code is as follows(hello.php):

```
<script>
function insert_db()
{

     <?php
     $username = $_POST['name'];
     print ($username);
     mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
     mysql_select_db("addressbook");

     mysql_query("insert into colleague values ('$username')");

     ?>


       }
 </script>

    <form  method="post">
   <input type="name" name="name" /><br />
   <input type="submit" name="mysubmit" value="Submit"  onclick="insert_db()"/>
```

On click of **submit** button ,**two entries** are  made into the database.One is blank and  other is entered value.
how to call the function only once??Is there any other way out..

Comment: You should read a few basic PHP tutorials before doing this. PHP is executed on the server when the page loads, not when a JavaScript function with it printed inside is called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't mix php and javascript like this. You see, the PHP will always be executed server-side, regardless where it is in the file (PHP does not know JavaScript). Therefore, the first time you load the page, it will insert an empty row (since $_POST['name'] is empty). Then, if you click submit, it will do nothing, since the JavaScript code ist empty, submit the form to the server and evaluate the PHP code again, this time with the desired effect.

A proper way to do this would be:

```
<?php
if (!empty($_POST['name'])){ // check if form values are there
    $username = $_POST['name'];
    print ($username);
    mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("addressbook");

    mysql_query("insert into colleague values ('$username')");
}
?>

<form  method="post">
    <input type="name" name="name" /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="mysubmit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

You might also want to work your way through a [PHP Tutorial](http://tut.php-quake.net/en/index.html) first

Answer (score 5):

You cannot, I repeat CANNOT, combine JS and PHP in this way.

Right-click the page, select View Source, and you will clearly see why.

PHP is run BEFORE the browser gets the page.

Therefore, you get an empty record when you load the form, then a filled one when you submit it because `$username` is defined that time.